# Align labels in DataVisualization.Charting effectively

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, charts

I need to develop a chart using datavisualization. Now the chart looks like 
below

[image]

In the above chart i am using rangebar to show min and max values, in rangebar the label (65---210) now comes in the middle part. But i need to show the min and max like one in red. ie min value in the start position of the rangebar and max value in the end position of the rangebar.

Please let me know if there is any way to do it

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it is by handling the chart's `Paint` event.
You would need to do some more sophisticated calculations using the `Graphics` object to make it work for the generic case. But it should get you started.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    float deltax, deltay, deltay2;
    Font font;
    Brush brush;
    Random r;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        deltax = 7.5F;
        deltay = 60;
        deltay2 = 5;

        font = new Font("Courier", 14);
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        r = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, new double[2] { r.Next(10, 40), r.Next(60, 90) }));
    }
    protected void Chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChartElement.ToString().Contains("Series"))
        {
            int count = Chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1;

            for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DataPoint dp = Chart1.Series[0].Points[i];

                float size = (float)(deltax*(dp.YValues[1] - dp.YValues[0] + deltay2));
                float x = (float)(deltax * dp.YValues[0]);
                float y = (float)(deltay * (count - dp.XValue + 2));
                e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("{0}", dp.YValues[0]), font, brush, new PointF(x, y));
                e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("{0}", dp.YValues[1]), font, brush, new PointF(x + size, y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks will let you know once it finished

Comment: as Vinu Sankar mentioned, how do we impliment this same code in mvc since we do not have Chart1_PostPaint event in mvc, do you have any idea on this?

Comment: You have to register to handle the event like this: `Chart1.PostPaint += Chart1_PostPaint;`.